# Getting all instances of an inner class from an instance of its outer class

Tags: java, oop, inner-classes, outer-classes

Let's say a `Tree` class has in inner `Node` class.

```java
class Tree {
    ...
    class Node {
        ...
    }
}
```

I know that within the context of a `Node` instance, the outer instance, or *the "owner"* of the `Node` can be accessed using the qualified `this`:

```java
Tree.this.someAction();
```

I'm looking for the exact opposite of this: a way to refer to and iterate over **all `Node`s *owned by* a given `Tree` object** without keeping an explicit collection field in `Tree`.

Is this even possible without reflection?

Comment: There is no out-of-the-box solution for this. You would have to write some bookkeeping-code yourself.

Comment: @Turing85 isn't this information already stored somewhere in the JVM? why not expose it to, at least, the owner class?

Comment: To get this information, one would have to get (at least) all objects of that type and check their `parent`-reference. Sonds awfully inefficient. As to the "why is it not exposed": this is something you should ask James Gosling, @brian-goetz or on the [JCP](https://www.jcp.org/en/home/index).

Comment: @brian-goetz = Brian Goetz ([StackOverflow profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3553087/brian-goetz), [Twitter profille](https://twitter.com/BrianGoetz))